# Working on a project without a connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, database-connection, visual-studio-express

I am trying to publish my website on the intranet server. From websites and suggestion I understood that i had to change the connection string to point to the database in the intranet server. While trying to do that i understand that i do not have a connectionstring in my web.config. Or maybe I am not having something similar to what that has been mentioned in the websites. Should I have added the connection string explicitly before I started working on the project? But my project works fine in my local machine with the local database.

So is it possible that a project can work without a connection string when working with local database or am I missing something really important? Now when I need to publish the project i could add a connection string in the web.Config file? I have a connection string portion commented out in my web.release. Should i uncomment the connection string in web.release or i add a new connection string in web.config.

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" requirePermission="false" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- So many dependent assembly -->
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Web.Release.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    <connectionStrings>
      <add connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" name="MyDB" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
</configuration>
```

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for web. Devloped application is a MVC5 web application. Database used Local DB. But i have copied the database into the intranet server using SSMS.

**Update : added config details**

Based on comments and answer i have added the following to my web.config

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings> 
    <add
    name="TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext"
    connectionString="Server=FE0VMC0643; Database=TeDaLSdev; "
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

And this is the connection string that i have in the properties of the database

```
Data Source=FE0VMC0643;Initial Catalog=TeDaLSdev;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Comment: @albireo :  thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it possible that a project can work without a connection string when working with local database or am I missing something really important?

If you're using Entity Framework (I don't know about other ORMs) and you don't specify a connection string it will internally create one pointing to LocalDB or SQLExpress by using the full name of your `DbContext`.

It's explained in [Entity Framework > Get Started > Connections and Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674):

> If you have not done any other configuration in your application, then calling the parameterless constructor on DbContext will cause DbContext to run in Code First mode with a database connection created by convention. […] uses the namespace qualified name of your derived context class […] as the database name and creates a connection string for this database using either SQL Express or LocalDb. If both are installed, SQL Express will be used.

If your database is not following the convention established by Entity Framework, then you either modify your database to have it following the convention or add a connection string for Entity Framework to use.

If your `DbContext` is

```
namespace MySolution.MyApplication.Contexts
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        […]
    }
}
```

either you have a database named `MySolution.MyApplication.Contexts.MyContext` in your `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` / `localhost\SQLExpress` instance or add the following connection string to your `App.config` / `Web.config`:

```
<add
    name="MySolution.MyApplication.Contexts.MyContext"
    connectionString="Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Yes I am using entity framework. So when I want to publish the project i do not have to add the connection string? But the name of the database is different from that of the current one. I suppose if my context name is `Tedalscontext` the name of the databse is also `tedalscontext`. But in the server i have a different name for the database. Should I make a databse with the same name in the server or add a new connection string?

Comment: Hopefully you're not using LocalDB or SQLExpress for a production application, hence yes, you have to add a connection string. The name of the database will be the fully qualified name of your DbContext, so if your DbContext is named `TedalsContext` and resides in the `My.Namespace` namespace the name of the database will be `My.Namespace.TedalsContext`. If you want Entity Framework to use a specific database, just add a connection string named as the fully qualified name of the `DbContext` and have it point where you like.

Comment: I believe you need to have a connection string for your prod environment. Please follow this link - http://screencast.com/t/1VrM1m9wUQsu.It shows an example.

Comment: I suggest you do next steps: 1. Add connection string to you dev database and test locally. 2. Add you prod database and server names to connection string and test live. Make sense?

Comment: Entity Framework will automatically create a connection string "by convention", the convention is to have a database named as the fully qualified name of the `DbContext`, so if your existing database does not follow this convention you have to add a connection string.

Comment: @Albireo: So i should have a database with the name exactly same as the db context. If my db context is  `tedalsContext` and i add a databse to the server with the same name. then the problem is resolved? is this what you meant?

Comment: That's not what I wrote. See the edited answer for an example.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the example. I have added the connection string as mentioned. I commented out the <entity framework> part in the config file. The program works. But now if i insert a value, shouldn't it be saved in the new database? it still saves in my local db. SHould I add something more?

Comment: Well, what is a name of your connectionString? Can you search cross the project for usage of that name?

Comment: i do not have any name for the connection string. And more than that if i search my whole project i can only find instances of `connectionstring` that are commented.

Comment: *I commented out the <entity framework> part in the config file.* What? Why did you do that? That's needed by Entity Framework. If you want to remove something *and* you're specifying a connection string, you can remove the `defaultConnectionFactory` node. *But now if i insert a value, shouldn't it be saved in the new database? it still saves in my local db.* It means you did something wrong, probably the name of the connection string.

Comment: Vini, can you show me a screenshot of your connection string from web.config file?

Comment: I wil update my question with the connection string i added. I will also add the connection string that is provided by the database.

Comment: @Albireo:  i commented that out because it was pointing to the local db.. so i though it was unnecessary :(

Comment: Well, can you connect to your database via SQLManagement Studio?

Comment: Yes. I can. I have tried adding a new table and have confirmed that i have all access rights.. and the question updated

Comment: So, right now you have an issue only with your live server, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96343/discussion-between-vnuuk-and-vini-vasundharan).

Comment: Let's discuss it in chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96343/discussion-between-vnuuk-and-vini-vasundharan

Comment: @Albireo : I had to add `base("name=Contextname")` and i could point to the correct database.